# Adding headers to TypedPipe

Tags: scala, cascading, scalding

I am using `scalding` `0.12` version with `TypedPipe`. I want to write the output to `csv` with headers. How can I add headers with this, I see the option for `writeHeader=true/false" but how do I provide the headers.

Comment: Do you have any code to share? At least the part which writes the output to `csv`?

Comment: The code is not much to share `TypedCsvWithHeader[String](outputString)`, this `TypedCsvWithHeader` just has `writeHeader=true`

Comment: What is the actual and expected result? Sharing (even a small chunk of code, along with the actual and expected results) makes it a lot easier for others to answer without making a lot of assumptions.

Comment: Actual result - just the output data `(val1, val2 ...)`
Expected result - `header1, header2 ...`
                            `val1, val2, ...`

Answer (score 1):

Using the type safe api, I write TSV files with the following code:

```
val data: TypedPipe[String, String] = ...
data.write(TypedTsv[(String, String)](outputPath))
```

`TypedPipe` is defined in the `TypedSeperatedFile` class. Take a look at the source code:

```
trait TypedSeperatedFile extends Serializable {
  def separator: String
  def skipHeader: Boolean = false
  def writeHeader: Boolean = false

  def apply[T: Manifest: TupleConverter: TupleSetter](path: String): FixedPathTypedDelimited[T] =
    apply(Seq(path))

  def apply[T: Manifest: TupleConverter: TupleSetter](path: String, f: Fields): FixedPathTypedDelimited[T] =
    apply(Seq(path), f)

  // others apply method
}

object TypedTsv extends TypedSeperatedFile {
  val separator = "\t"
}
```

One way to write a TSV with header is to implement your own object that extends the `TypedSeperatedFile` class:

```
object TypedTsvWithHeader extends TypedSeperatedFile {
  val separator = "\t"
  override val writeHeader = true
}
```

You can then use it as following:

```
data.write(TypedTsvWithHeader[(String, String)](outputPath,
  List("header1", "header2")))
```

Comment: I just realized that you were asking about csv... Luckily it's the same thing! TypedSeperatedFile contains a TypedCsv (and others) as well.

Answer (score 0):

> .write(Tsv("bcd.tsv", schema , writeHeader = true))

are you looking for something like this ?

Comment: I have tried this. But was not able to get the proper headers in. Can you provide a bit more details.